# StoryboardのUIView一部切り替えについて

Tags: ios, swift

下記のようなStoryboardがあるとします。
Main.storyboardの[SegmentA][SegmentB]をタップすると、
UIView2に、UIViewAまたはUIViewBを表示するようにしたいのですが、方法が分かりません。
外部のstoryboardの内容を一部UIVewのみ切り替えるということが
可能でしょうか？

Main.storyboard
┌──────┐
│UIView1   　  │
└──────┘
[SegmentA][SegmentB]
┌──────┐
│UIView2   　  │
└──────┘
┌──────┐
│UIView3    　 │
└──────┘

SubA.storyboard
┌──────┐
│UIViewA    　 │
└──────┘

SubB.storyboard
┌──────┐
│UIViewB   　  │
└──────┘

Answer (score 2, accepted):

下記の方法で実現できました。

```
// 同じ位置にViewを2つ用意
@IBOutlet weak var viewTest: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewTest2: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // 外部StoryBoardを取得しViewに追加
    let storyBoardSubA = UIStoryboard(name: "SubA", bundle: nil)
    let vcSubA = storyBoardSubA.instantiateInitialViewController() as! SubA
    self.viewTest.addSubview(vcSubA.view)

    let storyBoardSubB = UIStoryboard(name: "SubB", bundle: nil)
    let vcSubB = storyBoardSubB.instantiateInitialViewController() as! SubB
    self.viewTest2.addSubview(vcSubB.view)

    self.viewTest2.hidden = true
}

@IBAction func btnATouch(sender: UIButton) {
    // SubBを非表示
    self.viewTest.hidden = false
    self.viewTest2.hidden = true
}

@IBAction func btnBTouch(sender: UIButton) {
    // SubAを非表示
    self.viewTest.hidden = true
    self.viewTest2.hidden = false
}
```